# Black bar over a TableView just above TabBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

I have a `UITableView` with cells which perform a segue to an other simple detail view. The `UITableView` and detail view are embed in a Navigation Controller.

On my `UITableView` I put a `UISearchController` bar folowing this tutorial:
http://www.jhof.me/simple-uisearchcontroller-implementation/

So now, I have the following graphic problem:
When I perform a segue by tapping a cell after having make a research, I arrive to my detail view. But when I tap the Back button in the Navigation Bar, a mysterious black bar appears just above the TabBar. When the animation is over, the black bar disappears.

[image]

But when I tap the return button from the detail view without having done a research to arrive at this detail view, there is no black bar.

I can't understand why there is that black bar.
I just note the black bar's height is equal to the TabBar's height.
Maybe a link ?

**EDIT:**
I have solved the problem, it was linked with the TabBarController, but I don't understand why. I just have changed it and I made links with the different views again and particularly with my former bugged search view. After that, no more black bar...

Comment: Do you do anything in viewWillAppear on your table controller which could cause it? viewWill/DidAppear both get called again when you pop back. Also check your table view has bottom constraints pinning it to the bottom layout guide if its not a UITableViewController?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I haven't implemented viewWill/DidAppear methods, there is nothing from that both methods. Regarding to the layout, I haven't constraints because it's an entire TableViewController.

Comment: I think you have to make "unselected row" before move to the detail view.

Comment: Humm in other words ?

Comment: Try to delete your TabBar in IB, and make it again with the same links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by setting `extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars` to `YES` on the main table view.